# How do I set file permissions when opening a file in C++?

Tags: c++, unix, file-io

In C++, I want to open a file and set its permission, but I failed. Below is my program:

```
string filename="test.cnf";
ofstream ofile;
ofile.open(filename.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
ofile.close()
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::_Ios_Openmode'

error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
```

How to set the permission of the file to such as 644, 700?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not `O_RDONLY` mode for `fstream`. You should use one of:

1. `ios::app`
2. `ios::binary`
3. `ios::ate`
4. `ios::in`
5. `ios::out`
6. `ios::trunc`

Or their combinations (say `ios::app | ios::binary`). For your case you should use `ios::in` (maybe with `ios::binary`). Look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/) for more details.

Comment: many thanks for your quickly reply. That is very helpful for me to get clear my mistake.

Comment: This only handles the first part

Comment: This says nothing about the permission assigned to the file and is less than helpful.

Answer (score 7):

The option you seem to want to specify (`O_RDONLY`) isn't a
"permission", it's an access mode.  These are set implicitly according
to the combinations of `std::ios_base::in` and `std::ios_base::out`:
`in` alone results in `O_RDONLY`, `out` alone in `O_WRONLY` and `in |
out` in `O_RDWR`.

For the permissions on a created file, the answer is, rather annoyingly,
thet you can't specify them.  `std::filebuf::open()` (which is what
`std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` ultimately call) has no options or
provisions for passing in any indication of permissions to be used if it
must create the file.
The only way to do this is by using your system level functions (`open`
under Linux, `CreateFile` under Windows—despite the names, `open`
may create a file, and `CreateFile` will open an existing file, without
creating anything).  Using system level `open`/`CreateFile`, however,
means using system level `read`/`ReadFile` and `write`/`WriteFile`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is helpful. But I have to select the first person as the accept one, because he is much quickly. Sorry :-)

Comment: @zhaojing you are supposed to select the answer for accepting that is most correct / is the best answer.  It doesn't matter which came first

Answer (score 2):

If you are on unix systems, what you need is the "setmode" or "getmode" function.

From your shell command-line, type "man setmode"

Comment: I don't think `setmode` or `getmode` have anything to do with the OP's question.

Comment: Agree with @Billy. @malkia OP have problems with `std::ofstream` but you telling him how solve the problem if it were about `FILE*`.

Comment: Thanks to all! Yes, my problem is related with std:ofstream. But your method give me another way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. The second argument of fstream::open is a combination of flags chosen in ios::app, ios::binary, ios::ate, ios::in, ios::out, ios::trunc.
2. There is no standard C++ interface to set the access right.  The implementations I know are using 0666 which is then masked by the value set by umask(2). This is also the usual behavior of unix applications (the umask is inherited from the parent and shells have a builtin umask command).  My recommandation is that you do nothing and rely on the umask set by the user. If that is not applicable, temporarily change the umask in your app.