# Setting file permissions when opening a file with ofstream

Tags: c++, linux, file-permissions, fstream

Is there a way in C++'s standard libraries (or linux sys/stat.h, sys/types.h, sys/.... libraries) to set the file permissions of a file when creating it with `ofstream` (or using something else from those libraries)?

When I create a file it just gets created with some default set of file permissions (I assume whatever the current `umask` is), but I want to explicitly set the permissions to something other than the default (ex. `600`), and I can't just set the umask before starting the program (b/c others will run it).

```
// Example of creating a file by writing to it
ofstream fp(filename.c_str())

/* write something to it */
```

Is there a way to do this in C++ or if not, a way to set the `umask` within the C++ program?

For example, in C's standard library you [can just do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245212/2487336):

```
open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666)
```

but I don't want to resort to using the C function, as it'd be nice to be able to use the functions associated with `fstream` objects.

(*Side Note: there was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274598/how-do-i-set-file-permissions-when-opening-a-file-in-c) whose title was exactly what I was looking for, but it turned out to be unrelated.*)

Comment: No, C++ is not aware of file permissions. (Create the file first, using system function(s) and than open the C++stream)

Comment: Do you mean something like opening the file using C's `open` function, close that file descriptor, then open it again using `ofstream`?

Comment: There is the experimental [Filesystem library TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs)

Comment: @NathanOliver, who would've guessed? In 2015 we finally realized we DO need a way to create or read directory in C++ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot.  The standard library must be platform agnostic, and permissions like `0600` are meaningless on Windows for example.  If you want to use platform-specific features, you'll need to use platform-specific APIs.  Of course, you can always call `umask()` before you open the file, but that's not part of the C++ standard library, it's part of the platform API.

Note: `open()` isn't part of the C standard library either.  It's a platform API.  The C standard library function to open a file is `fopen()`.

Comment: This is true right now but there is a TS out there for filesystems that will allow us do this portably.  [Filesystem library TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs)

Comment: That TS is great for a lot of things, but permissions are not among the things it does well (on non-linux systems at least).

Comment: I haven't played with it yet so I'll take your word on it.

Answer (score 9):

In C++17, `std::filesystem::permissions` was introduced. It will enable you to get and set permissions in a platform-agnostic manner.

Get permissions:

```
using fs = std::filesystem;
bool owner_can_read =
    fs::status("my_file.txt").permissions() & fs::perms::owner_read != fs::perms::none;
```

Set permissions (add all permissions for owner and group, that is, add modes 0x770 on unix):

```
using fs = std::filesystem;
fs::permissions("my_file.txt",
                fs::perms::owner_all | fs::perms::group_all,
                fs::perm_options::add);
```

Example based on an example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/permissions).